# Best way to wait till the status changes

Tags: selenium2, test-design, browser-automation

I have to automate a web page. Which has the following behaviour.

I will create an application and the created application will be displayed in a table.

The table has a column named status. The status of the created application will be complete after some time. Till then the status will be processing. Or status will be error. So from processing state it can go either completed or error.

Now if i want to check the status of the created application. How will I approach to solve this problem? I need to keep on pooling the status until it becomes completed?

What will be your design approach to this problem?

I'm using selenium web driver.

Comment: See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=wait

Answer (score 1):

you can use waitforpageload option or implicitly wait options to make the page wait and after that you can make a note that it is success or failiure.

I hope though wait can be used or it might give some solution to the problem.